# Replace only the last match using preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex

So, for example user input some regex match and he wants that last match will be replaced by input-string.

Example:

```
$str = "hello, world, hello!";

// For now, regex will be for example just word, 
// but it should work with match too
replaceLastMatch($str, "hello", "replacement"); 

echo $str; // Should output "hello, world, replacement!";
```

Comment: what do you mean? using form action with two input fields

Answer (score 1):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure that you only match the last occurrence of the search string:

```
function replaceLastMatch($str, $search, $replace) {
    $pattern = sprintf('~%s(?!.*%1$s)~', $search);
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $str, 1);
}
```

Usage:

```
$str = "hello, world, hello!";
echo replaceLastMatch($str, 'h\w{4}', 'replacement');
echo replaceLastMatch($str, 'hello', 'replacement');
```

Output:

```
hello, world, replacement!
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/157803)

Comment: Hello, i saw this and want ask you if there was not problem if i would reverse match in preg_replace.

Comment: @user3684432: I'm not sure what you're asking. The actual string, search term, or the replacement does not get altered in any way. They are used as it is. You can't tell `preg_replace()` to start from the end, so you just reverse everything and replace the first occurrence using the `limit` parameter.

Comment: So will it work even when I input in $search reg ex? For example "^[a-zA-Z]"?

Comment: You can test that, but it shouldn't matter what the search is @user3684432

Comment: @user3684432: Yes, it would work as long as the first parameter is a valid regex pattern. If you're going to use an actual regex pattern as opposed to a search string, you don't need the `strrev()` there any more.

Comment: But [`preg_quote($search)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) escaped all regex syntax elements so you can't search with a pattern. I believe user368... wants the user to be able to search by pattern.

Comment: `@`user3684432: I thought it was obvious already, but in case it wasn't: as @Lukas notes above, you should also remove the `preg_quote()` from the function if you want to be able to search with a pattern. Or adjust it accordingly so you can escape whatever part you want.

Comment: @AmalMurali Then again, I don't get how the matching with e.g. `[A-Z]{3,5}` is going to work with `strrev()` when your regex ends up as `/}5,3{]Z-A[/`.

Comment: If the OP wants to use a regex pattern as the search parameter, they can just remove the `strrev()` from the first parameter. If they want to also include a user-input string and *then* construct the pattern, then just reverse the string alone, i.e. `preg_replace("/someregexpattern".strrev($search)."moreregex/");` @Lukas

Comment: @AmalMurali as I understood, the `$search` parameter can also be a regex. However, reverting a regex will almost certainly break it. Hence, you either need some clever way to revert the regex without breaking it, or you find a method to only find and replace the last instance (see my answer).

Comment: @Lukas It should be easy enough to add an additional function parameter (a boolean) that determines thr search type, i.e. plain text or regex. In any case, I think my answer should get the OP started.

Comment: So, if it's a plain text search it would use your approach, but a regex search should use Lukas's, is that what you're saying?  Because your approach is never going to work with regexes.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Yeah, sorry about the confusion. I've updated my answer to include an alternative approach that works with regexes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

**Short version:**

It is vulnerable though (e.g. if user uses groups `(abc)`, this will break):

```
function replaceLastMatch($string, $search, $replacement) {
    // Escape all / as it delimits the regex
    // Construct the regex pattern to be ungreedy at the right (? behind .*)
    $search = '/^(.*)' . str_replace('/', '\\/', $search) . '(.*?)$/s';

    return preg_replace($search, '${1}' . $replacement . '${2}', $string);
}
```

---

**Longer version** (personally recommended):

This version allows the user to use groups without interfering with this function (e.g. pattern `((ab[cC])+(XY)*){1,5}`):

```
function replaceLastMatch($string, $search, $replacement) {
    // Escape all '/' as it delimits the regex
    // Construct the regex pattern to be ungreedy at the right (? behind .*)
    $search = '/^.*(' . str_replace('/', '\\/', $search) . ').*?$/s';

    // Match our regex and store matches including offsets
    // If regex does not match, return $string as-is
    if(1 !== preg_match($search, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
        return $string;

    return substr($string, 0, $matches[1][1]) . $replacement
           . substr($string, $matches[1][1] + strlen($matches[1][0]));
}
```

One general warning: You should be *very* careful with user input, as it can do all kings of nasty stuff. Be always prepared for inputs that are rather "unproductive".

---

**Explanation:**

The core of the *match last* functionality is the `?` (greediness inversion) operator (see [*Repetition*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) - somewhere in the middle).

While repetition patterns (e.g. `.*`) are *greedy* by default, consuming *as much as it can possibly match*, making a pattern *ungreedy* (e.g. `.*?`) will make it match *as little as possible* (while still matching at all).

Hence, in our case, the greedy front part of the pattern will always have precedence over the non-greedy back part and our custom middle part will match the very last instance possible.

Comment: +1, but it's actually the first, *greedy* `.*` that makes this work.  You really don't need to add anything to the end, but if do, it doesn't matter if you use `.*$` or `.*?$`, it's just going to takes what's left.  It won't engage in a tug-of-war with the first `.*`.  Greediness doesn't affect where a match *starts*, only where it *ends*.

Comment: One more thing.  You seem to be assuming the regex provided by the user is not already enclosed in delimiters, and if it contains any slashes, they are not already escaped.  Of course, slashes have no special meaning in regexes, but many regex users escape them anyway.

Comment: Regarding user input and regex expressions, [preg_quote()](http://php.net/preg_quote) exists for exactly this reason. Be sure to tack on the second parameter with your pattern character (e.g. '/')

Comment: @AlanMoore people escape them so as to prevent a PHP error, for example. If your pattern was /foo(bar)/abc/, PHP will flip out (or maybe just warn you and fail... either way.)

Comment: @John The purpose of the question was to enable a user to enter a regular expression, so `preg_quote()` is __not__ an option here.